# A program that finds the average of a number of integers

Tags: java

I have integers a, b, c, d. I want to design a program which will output me the average of the numbers after discarding the highest and the lowest numbers. So if I have input 3 7 5 3, I would want output 4. I have to do this without using the math library, loops or arrays. My code is below. It runs but gives the wrong output. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class average{
 public static void main(String[] args) {


  int a, b, c, d;
  a = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
  b = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
  c = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
  d = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);

  if ((a>b)&&(a>c)&&(a>d))
  {a= 0;
  }
  if ((a<b)&&(a<c)&&(a<d))
  {a= 0;
  }

  if ((b>a)&&(b>c)&&(b>d))
    {b=0;
  }

  if ((b<a)&&(b<c)&&(b<d))
  {b=0;
  }



  if ((c>a)&&(c>b)&&(c>d))
  {c=0;
  }

  if ((c<a)&&(c<b)&&(c<d))
  {c=0;
  }

  if ((d>a)&&(d>b)&&(d>c))
  {d=0; 
  }

  if ((d<a)&&(d<b)&&(d<c))
  {d=0;
  }


  int x;
  // x is the average of all the numbers excluding the largest and the smallest 

  x= ((a+b+c+d)/2);

  System.out.println(x);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking the question? Is the result not what you expect? Can you add the tag for your programming language, otherwise hardly anyone will see your question.

Comment: no it gives me 5 for input 3 3 5 7

Comment: Your question has the tags `compiler-errors` and `runtime-error`, suggesting the code doesn't run, yet you say it has a result?

Comment: **Error:** When you set a variable to zero, the next `if` will not work as you expect.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong tag! I will change it. What would be an appropriate tag?

Comment: At least a tag for your programming language. Don't forget to mention, in your question, what your problem with the piece of code is: It runs but returns 5 not 4. I think you will be surprised in how few lines of code this can be done.

Comment: i'm sure there are much easier ways to do this but this is for a beginner level class and as such we can't use anything we haven't done yet.

Comment: Could you suggest how to work around the error that you pointed out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Java, so I would not be able to make a good suggestion. However, now that you know what the problem is, perhaps you can find a solution yourself? Isn't that the point of the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if conditions you provided do not work as expected when two or more numbers are same, which is explained clearly by Rai.

You can store the minimum and maximum values in min and max variables.

```
int min = a, max = a;
if(b > max)
{
    max = b;
}
if(c > max)
{
    max = c;
}
if(d > max)
{
    max = d;
}
```

Similarly for min.

And when you are summing the numbers for average, just add all four numbers and subtract the sum of min and max.

I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

in your input example 3 3 5 7, a and b are equal. but your code only compares for less than (<) value, so when your code execution reaches line “x= ((a+b+c+d)/2);” you have a=3, b=3 and c=5  which results into x =5.

Hope this explains why you are not getting expected result.

Comment: how do I correct that? would I have to alter my conditions?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and short solution where there is no loop, no arrays and math library is not used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[] {"3", "7", "5", "3"};

    int a = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    int c = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
    int d = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(a);
    numbers.add(b);
    numbers.add(c);
    numbers.add(d);

    Integer min = numbers.stream().min(Integer::compare).get();
    Integer max = numbers.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();

    numbers.remove(min);
    numbers.remove(max);

    int average = (numbers.get(0) + numbers.get(1)) / 2;
    System.out.println("average: " + average);
}
```

Comment: I can't use arrays, loops or the math library!

Comment: there is no loop, no arrays and math library is not used there

Comment: List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();                                           Integer min = numbers.stream().min(Integer::compare).get();                                 numbers.remove(min);                                                                                               I am not familiar with any of these and most of the rest of the code, I JUST started out so I know only very beginner level code, and thats all i can use to solve this

Comment: List is not array: https://beginnersbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Java-collection-framework-hierarchy.png